# How do lambda parameters map in TakeWhile?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm learning LINQ using the [101 LINQ Samples in the MSDN page](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Partitioning-Operators-c68aaccc#TakeWhileIndexed) and I came across this code:

```
int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };

var firstSmallNumbers = numbers.TakeWhile((n, index) => n >= index);

foreach (var n in firstSmallNumbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

The purpose of this function is to "use TakeWhile to return elements starting from the beginning of the array until a number is hit that is less than its position in the array."

How exactly the `n` and `index` know which parameter to take? (i.e. how does `n` know it will take `5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0` and how does `index` know it will do an increment of 0, 1, 2, 3...)?

Comment: I changed your title. If it doesn't mean what you meant, please change it.

Comment: I agreed with your changes, thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the overload is defined that way. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548775(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeWhile<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate
)
```

The `predicate` argument is described as follows:

> A function to test each source element for a condition; the second
>   parameter of the function represents the index of the source element.

The `TSource` argument is the item, and the `int` is the index. The `bool` is the return value.

When you write `(n, index) => ...` the `n` takes the first parameter (`TSource`) and `index` takes the second (`int`).

Comment: So you are saying it doesn't matter how I name the parameters? (i.e. I can rename it to `(somethingElse1, somethingElse2) =>` and it will still work?

Comment: @C.J. Thats right. You are defining an anonymous method, the parameter names are up to you.

Comment: @C.J. Try it and find out.  You already have the code to do it.

Answer (score 4):

In a lambda expression, everything before `=>` are parameters to the method. As an example, the `(n, index) => n >= index` lambda expression can be rewritten as a method similar to this:

```
public bool CheckIfValueIsGreaterOrEqualToIndex(int value, int index)
{
    if(value >= index)
    {
         return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So, using that method, you can specify whatever name you want to the parameters (in this instance I used `value` instead of `n`). And instead of the lambda you could use that method here:

```
numbers.TakeWhile(CheckIfValueIsGreaterOrEqualToIndex);
```

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter `n` is associated with the number on numbers and the second the `index` is associated with the index of the number in the sequence. Actually, it doesn't matter if you name them `n` and `index`, you could name whatever. In any case the first parameter would be associated with the random item in the sequence and and the second parameter with the index of this sequence.

As more formally Bradley stated above the definition of `TakeWhile` is the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeWhile<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate
)
```

As we see from the above the `TakeWhile` is an extension method defined on types that implements the `IEnumerable` interface. Note now two things, the parameters that takes as input this method and it's return type.

It return a sequence of objects of the type of the objects that are in the supplied sequence.

What it takes as a parameter?

A predicate. A predicate is a method that takes some parameters and returns either `true` or `false`. What are the parameters of the predicate?

The parameters of the predicate are a `TSource` element, and an `int`. The `TSource` element would be the random element of your sequence the `int` would be the index of this element.

What is this `(n, index) => n >= index` now?

This is a lambda expression, which acts like a predicate.

Specifficaly, given the variables called `n` and `index`, returns `true` if `n>=index`, otherwise returns `false.` Supplying this expression to the `TakeWhile` extension method is like passing there a `Func<TSource, int, bool>` predicate. So you get what you want.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it came on a much earlier revision of your answer. I'm guessing they haven't looked at this (much better) version.

Answer (score 2):

The best method would be to try and implement your own simplified `TakeWhile` method:

```
public static List<int> MyTakeWhile(this List<int> input, Func<int, int, bool> predicate)
{
    var result = new List<int>();
    for (var i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
    {
        if (predicate(input[i], i))
            result.Add(input[i]);
        else
            break;
    };
    return result;
}
```

You would use an `yield return` in real life, and return an `IEnumerable` and, of course, use generics instead of `int`. But the idea is the same.

If you want to test it:

```
var numbers = new List<int> { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
var result = numbers.MyTakeWhile((n, index) => n >= index);
result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

It should give `{5, 4}` which is exactly the same as the original `TakeWhile`.

Comment: Even though this is a reasonable way to learn; it doesn't really help teach the OP how lambda expressions work.